# Code is not running when i try to compare two sheets using xlrd in python

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to compare two sheets from my excel and list the row that is not matching from sheet1 using xlrd in python.

Sheet1:

```
Name    Gender  Age
John    M   30
Moses   F   28
```

Sheet2:

```
Name    Gender  Age
John    M   30
Moses   F   29
```

---

```
import xlrd as xl
loc = "C:/Users/S22JK3/Desktop/Sample.xlsx"
wb = xl.open_workbook(loc)
sheet1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet2 = wb.sheet_by_index(1)

row1 = sheet1.nrows
column1 = sheet1.ncols
row2 = sheet2.nrows
column2 = sheet2.ncols

row = max(row1,row2)
column = max(column1,column2)

for i in range(row):
     for j in range(column):
        if sheet1.cell(i,j) != sheet2.cell(i,j):
print(sheet1.cell(i,j))
```

When i try to run the above code, I am getting error as "Expected an indented block"

Comment: give 3 tabs at line `print(sheet1.cell(i,j))`
`

Comment: Not tabs, you should be using 4 spaces per level of indentation. The last line needs to be indented under the `if` condition. Also, the error has nothing to do with the title, this is standard Python syntax

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code indentation and logic.

Use this:

```
import xlrd as xl

loc = "C:/Users/S22JK3/Desktop/Sample.xlsx"
wb = xl.open_workbook(loc)
sheet1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet2 = wb.sheet_by_index(1)

row1 = sheet1.nrows
column1 = sheet1.ncols
row2 = sheet2.nrows
column2 = sheet2.ncols

row = max(row1,row2)
column = max(column1,column2)

for i in range(row):
    for j in range(column):
        if sheet1.cell(i,j) != sheet2.cell(i,j):
            print(sheet1.cell(i,j))
```